# React with tinyMCE - how to output HTML without seeing balises in front-end?

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, blogs

I'm a new user of TinyMCE, and i'm trying to incorporate it in my React App. But i'ma actually getting an output problem. When try "format:text" in the tiny component, and try to create a post in my blog using bold and italic options, when the post is posted, the displayed text is just normal, without bold or italic properties. So, I've tried the "format:html" but in this case, I get my text without any styles at all, AND we see the `<p>` balises.

So, it can looks like a stupid question but, how do we output the posted text correctly ?

As always, thx in advance !

Comment: Hi! Could you please share your TinyMCE config? By `format:text` and `format:html` do you mean `getContent({ format: "text" })` and `getContent({ format: "html" })`? How exactly are these methods used in your project? Some examples would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me as well. If you do not want to see the  attributes on your output then go to the React Component which is responsible for output and in your React component when you use the return() keyword you should create a div use the
**dangerouslySetInnerHTML** attribute inside.

**Example**:
Here's [a link] (https://blog.logrocket.com/using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-in-a-react-application/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).